# Fail to compare servers by manufacturer_id with ipmi exporter metrics on prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I need to create a query to compare which servers have high temperature, but only HP servers.

For instance:
If it is HP the temperature should NOT be higher than 40.
If it is Supermicro, it should not be higher than 50.

I created a query, but it does not work. I would appreciate to know if it is a bug or I am crossing the data wrong.

`(ipmi_bmc_info{manufacturer_id="Hewlett-Packard (11)",job="ipmi"} == 1) and (ipmi_temperature_celsius{name="02-CPU 1",job="ipmi"} > 40)`

Answer (score 0):

Since your metrics have different sets of labels you need to need to explain Prometheus how to [match them](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching):

```
(ipmi_bmc_info{manufacturer_id="Hewlett-Packard (11)",job="ipmi"} == 1)
  and on (instance) (ipmi_temperature_celsius{name="02-CPU 1",job="ipmi"} > 40)
```

In this example `on (instance)` instructs Prometheus to get all time series `(ipmi_bmc_info{manufacturer_id="Hewlett-Packard (11)",job="ipmi"} == 1)` that have at least one times series `(ipmi_temperature_celsius{name="02-CPU 1",job="ipmi"} > 40)` with matching `instance`.

Additionally, if you want to use this query in alerting rules or visualization you most likely want to swap parts of the query:

```
ipmi_temperature_celsius{name="02-CPU 1",job="ipmi"} > 40
  and on (instance) ipmi_bmc_info{manufacturer_id="Hewlett-Packard (11)",job="ipmi"} == 1
```

That way your query would return `ipmi_temperature_celsius` with its value and labels.